# I'm getting error when I try to include JacksonSoft.CustomTabControl in c# winform application

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi guys I'm developing a SQLite Inspector and I want use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition) tabcontrol. I have included it in the project and in design time works great. But in Runtime JIT raise an error in `InitializeComponent()`
This is the Message

```
Impossibile caricare il file o l'assembly 'JacksonSoft.CustomTabControl, Version=1.0.1.7, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=53c237210c7e462d' o una delle relative dipendenze. Tentativo di caricare un programma con un formato non corretto.
```

And this is the StackTrace

```
   in SQLiteInspector.Form1.InitializeComponent()
   in SQLiteInspector.Form1..ctor() in c:\Users\Fabio\Desktop\Visual studio prjects\C#\SQLiteInspector\SQLiteInspector\Form1.cs:riga 17
```

Comment: As the first message says, the format of the assembly is not correct. Have you tried redownloading the file and re-referencing it?

Comment: Yes I have tried but it dosen't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the DLL downloaded is 32-bit but you are running on a 64-bit machine with an exe flagged as either x64 or AnyCPU.

To fix this either:

- Download the source for the control and build it yourself as "AnyCPU"
- Change your exe to "x86"

Answer (score 0):

I found the original source for this project. (no longer supported)  However, you can build locally and update for your purposes.

https://github.com/Nickelony/CustomTabControl

I had similar issue, updating legacy project, but end up keeping the control after I was able to build in framework v4.8